# why is dd oflag=direct slower to write to block devices vs writing to files?

Tags: performance, unix

I am trying to compare aggregate write rates when writing to a file in a GPFS file system, as compared to writing directly to disk on a system with GNU/Linux. For my application I need to measure the raw rate i.e. without taking advantage of cache. I do not understand the impact of the direct option used with dd to bypass cache. When writing directly to block device, I get a drastically lower rate when I use oflag=direct, as compared with writing to a file in the GPFS file system. Why does this happen?

To measure aggregate rates I create p processes running dd that write concurrently to the block device or file. I then sum the p rates obtained to get the aggregate write rate.

**Results:** The write rate of each of 30 processes is as follows:

1. writing to disk using conv=fsync option, each process gets a write rate of ~180MB/s
2. writing to disk using both conv=fsync and oflag=direct, each process gets a write rate of ~9MB/s
3. Writing to a file in GPFS file system, using both conv=fsync and oflag=direct, gets a write rate of ~80MB/s

   ```
   numprocs=30
   directdiskrate=~/scratch/rate5
   syncdiskrate=~/scratch/rate4
   filerate=~/scratch/rate3

   #using both conv=fsync and oflag=direct, each process gets a write rate of ~9MB/s
   writetodiskdirect="dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdac bs=256k count=4096 conv=fsync oflag=direct iflag=fullblock"
   for p in $(seq $numprocs)
   do
            #parses output of dd, rate is on last line, each field separated by ,s
           $writetodiskdirect 2>&1|tail -n 1|awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $3 }'|sed -e 's/MB\/s//g'>>$directdiskrate&
   done
   wait

   #using only conv=fsync option, each process gets a write rate of ~180MB/s
   writetodisksync="dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdac bs=256k count=4096 conv=fsync iflag=fullblock"
   for p in $(seq $numprocs)
   do
            #parses output of dd, rate is on last line, each field separated by ,s
           $writetodisksync 2>&1|tail -n 1|awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $3 }'|sed -e 's/MB\/s//g'>>$syncdiskrate&
   done
   wait

   #using both conv=fsync and oflag=direct for a file, gets a write rate of ~80MB/s
   for p in $(seq $numprocs)
   do
           writetofile="dd if=/dev/zero of=/gpfs1/fileset6/file$p bs=256k count=4096 conv=fsync oflag=direct"
            #parses output of dd, rate is on last line, each field separated by ,s
           $writetofile 2>&1|tail -n 1|awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $3 }'|sed -e 's/MB\/s//g'>>$filerate&
   done
   wait
   ```

Thanks,
Amy

Comment: Mind sharing the results of your test? It'll give us more clues to work on. Your question is likely to be OS/filesystem specific, so details on that would be great. You might also want to tweak you block sizes and compare results if you consider this question - http://superuser.com/questions/586404/why-does-dd-copy-slower-with-really-small-and-really-big-block-sizes

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question accordingly. Will try different block sizes as well.